# Declaring a variable in a Linux kernel file to be used in a custom C file?

Tags: c, linux, global-variables

So I have been researching this tirelessly and nothing seems to be working. All I want to do is initialize an int to 0 on startup. Currently, I am in /kernel/sys.c and I have

**/kernel/sys.c**

```
int process_log_level;
EXPORT_SYMBOL(process_log_level);
```

Below that is some custom system calls that simply increment the variable. The system calls are called in the file below, and the variable increments just fine if you run

```
sudo dmesg -c
```

but all I want to have my C file read int process_log_level.
I have the variable declared like this.
**../process_log/process_log.c**

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "process_log.h"

extern int process_log_level;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("process_log_level = %d", process_log_level);
    return 0;
}
```

Whenever I try to compile the file I get told there is an undefined reference to "process_log_level." All I want to do is be able to access this variable in process_log.c. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: It makes no sense. The question is like: my neighbor has water. How can I use my neighbors water? Well, you can't. Unless the neighbor allows you to.

Comment: I was under the impression that was the purpose of the EXPORT_SYMBOL() macro. Doesn't it allow other modules to use the selected function/variable?

Comment: _other modules_ - yes. Not userspace programs.

Comment: Am I going about this completely wrong then? I have been hung up on the EXPORT_SYMBOL thing for a while now. I feel like this can't be a hard problem to solve, but I don't know where else to turn if this doesn't work.

Comment: EXPORT_SYMBOL lets other modules use the symbol. Normal programs can't use *any* symbols from the kernel. Only modules can.

Comment: Put the variable in the /sys virtual filesystem.  Then userspace can read and write it.

Answer (score 0):

Userspace and kernel communicate via system calls.

> Below that is some custom system calls
>
> all I want to have my C file read int process_log_level.

So just add another system call that would return the value to userspace program. Then call that syscall from your program to retrieve the value from kernelspace.

Comment: A real driver would add a device file or something, not a system call